# Como desabilitar um botão em java sem retirar sua cor

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Tenho um botão que, ao clicá-lo ele muda de cor, mas se clicar nele novamente nada deve acontecer. Porém ainda não consigo bloquear essa ação.
Tentei esse codigo:

```
private void Button1_1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    if(TextoJogador.getText().equals("Jogador 1")){
        Button1_1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        TextoJogador.setText("Jogador 2");
        play(sound);

    }else{
        Button1_1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        TextoJogador.setText("Jogador 1");
        play(sound);
    }
    Button1_1.setEnable(false); //essa parte que faz o button perder a cor
}
```

mas o botão perde a cor que foi selecionada ao ser desativado.

Comment: Qual é a cor inicial do botão (antes de qualquer clique)?

Comment: Nenhuma cor. ele só obtem uma cor apos o primeiro clique, isso é um jogo da velha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendo o `setEnabled(false)` muda a aparência do botão mesmo, não tem jeito. Mas experimente assim:

```
private void Button1_1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (Button1_1.getBackground() != Color.CYAN && Button1_1.getBackground() != Color.GREEN) {
        if(TextoJogador.getText().equals("Jogador 1")){
            Button1_1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            TextoJogador.setText("Jogador 2");
            play(sound);

        }else{
            Button1_1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            TextoJogador.setText("Jogador 1");
            play(sound);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: irei complementar a pergunta

Comment: Veja agora se atende

Comment: Perfeito mano, não havia pensado nisso :) obrigado!

Comment: Beleza, só aceitar a resposta então, clicando no ✓ do lado esquerdo e votando +1. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre por causa do [LookAndFeel(LAF)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html), pois é ele quem define as estilizações de todos os componentes do swing. Se você aplicar o LAF `Metal`, que é um LAF mais básico, esse problema não irá acontecer.

Porém, imagino que esteja utilizando o Nimbus, que é o LAF padrão de projetos criados pelo netbeans, ainda tem como alterar direto nele, mas a outra resposta acaba sendo mais simples e viável, sem ter que deixar a aparência da aplicação mais básica.

Se quiser se aventurar em alterar o LAF, pode adicionar apenas a linha abaixo dentro do main, antes de iniciar a tela:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
```

Com isso, o `setEnabled(false)`  não afeta o background que você alterou inicialmente do botão, porém, como consequência de ser um tema básico, sua aplicação fica com uma aparência mais rudimentar, quando comparada ao Nimbus.